# Access HttpSession where my @ResponseBody is , in spring mvc framework

Tags: ajax, session, spring-mvc

I tried a lot but i can not find any solution.

I want to access `HttpSession` because i want **userId** of current loggedIn User which i set in session attribute.

Is there any problem with `@ResponseBody` , or some other problem.

**MyController.java**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/samplechat", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String chatByAtmosphere(HttpSession session) {
    Person person = getPerson();
    UserLogin user = person.getUserId();
    String userId = user.getId();
    session.setAttribute("userId",userId);
    return "home";
 }


 @RequestMapping(value = "/websockets", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public void post(@RequestBody String msg,HttpSession session)
 throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

      String userId = (String)session.getAttribute("userId");    
      msg=userId+" : " +msg;
      System.out.println(msg);

  }
 }
```

**home.jsp**

In my home jsp i provide url in this format "/../websockets" which is correct i checked it.

#### But the point is i am not able to access session variable userId , it shows me null.

Comment: [This](http://www.javaroots.com/2013/08/how-to-get-session-object-in-spring-mvc.html) might help you out

Comment: Thanks it helps me. But if I use AtmosphereResource in @ResponseBody than i am not able to aceess HttpSession. Any solution for it.